# Android setting images inside listView

Tags: android, image, listview, bitmap, drawable

So i have this listview with my custom XML file that i made for it.

In the file, there is an image with no source set that has a fixed id.

I want to change this image source to one of my resources in drawable folder.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/listImage"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:contentDescription="protection image"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
/>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" 
android:textSize="20dp"  
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
android:textSize="12dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what i have tried so far, and it crashes:

```
        adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.custom_row_view,new String[]{"name", "current"},  new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});
    ImageView img;
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listImage);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.opened);
    img.setImageDrawable(d);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: do u want to set same images all list items or different images for each list item ?

Comment: I have two images, and i need to decide which items gets what image

Comment: what is your condition to decide the image for list item?

Comment: its not here, the condition is a simple if statement. i haven't done that yet because i want to see if setting the image even works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView img;
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listImage);
```

This means that you are referring to a object with is present in the layout which you could have used for your Activity's **setContentView()**.But your ImageView is not present in that layout.

And  here you are trying to refer this with a ListView. So obviously you are getting the null pointer exception.

You have to make use of a Custom Adapter as well as. Try the one from the below link.

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: Im not sure i understand these examples.. Isn't there any simple way just to change the image if i have the id?

Comment: No. Not possible with a Custom Listview. You have to make use of Custom Adapter only.

Comment: Well, but my listview has two lines. is it possible to adapt this too?

Comment: Yes, with custom listview anything is possible. Give it a try. I can't be done this simple.

Comment: But i dont know how to do this with two lines. any examples?

Comment: Doing this wont be possible since my whole application is based on another adapter. i have managed to display a fixed image, just not to change it. is there any way to do that?

Comment: am sorry. I don't know any other way to do this.

Comment: Ahh.. then is there any way you can show me how to do this with two lines of text? and i also need all the onListItemClick events i currently have... will they change?